# Typescript & operator

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling to find the definition of the `&` operator in TypeScript. I have recently come across the following code:

```js
type IRecord<T> = T & TypedMap<T>;
```

What does that operator do, and how is it different from the union type `|`?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This looks like it's from the [**Intersection Types**](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.5.4/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#35-intersection-types) portion of the Language Specification. Specifically, the `&` is an [**intersection type literal**](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.5.4/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#3.8.7). As for what it does:

> Intersection types represent values that simultaneously have multiple types. A value of an intersection type A & B is a value that is both of type A and type B. Intersection types are written using intersection type literals (section 3.8.7).

The spec goes on to offer a helpful snippet to better understand the behavior:

```js
interface A { a: number }  
interface B { b: number }

var ab: A & B = { a: 1, b: 1 };  
var a: A = ab;  // A & B assignable to A  
var b: B = ab;  // A & B assignable to B
```

Because `ab` is both of type `A` *and* of type `B`, we can assign it to `a` and/or `b`. If `ab` were only of type `B`, we could only assign it to `b`.

The code you shared may be from [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/341#issuecomment-147523795), which mentions Intersection Types.

Comment: Looks like the links to the spec are outdated. Can be found here 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types

Answer (score 8):

Worth noting that if you'd prefer to use interfaces over types (although they're largely similar) that you can typically use [**interface extension**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces) instead of [**type intersection**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) like this:

```
// base type
interface Shape {
  color: string;
}

// extension
interface Square extends Shape {
  sideLength: number;
}

// intersection
type Square = Shape & {
  sideLength: number;
}
```

**See Also**: [Difference between extending and intersecting interfaces in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52681316/1366033)