# TypeScript Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.'

Tags: typescript

I have an object property with the following signature.

```
handleItem = (data: Output & { isValid: boolean }) => {}
```

I do not understand the `&` part.

Basically I trying to pass some arguments as:

```
handleItem (outputItem, { isValid: false })
```

and I receive an error

`Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.'`

How to pass values property? How the `&` is used in this instance?

Comment: It looks like `& { isValid: boolean }` is describing the `data: Output` part. This makes sense, considering there should be one argument.

Comment: Everything after the `:` is a type annotation. The function only takes a single object as argument. (And that object needs to contain an `isValid` property.)

Comment: handleItem = (data: Output, obj: { isValid: boolean }) => {}

Comment: so the isValid is optional?

Comment: not sure ,could you please provide me an example how to call this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`handleItem` takes a single argument, an object that has the properties of `Output` and the `isValid` property. You need to construct such an object. Using the spread operator is a good option:

```
handleItem ({ isValid: false, ...outputItem })
```

You can read more about intersection types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: this one does the trick thanks

Answer (score 3):

this is called `Intersection Type` and it means that your `param` of your `handleItem()` method combines `Output` and `{ isValid: boolean }` - will say that your parameter needs to have both types, `Output` and `{ isValid: boolean }`.

[Typescript & operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875609/typescript-operator)

so you need to call it this way:

```
handleItem ({ isValid: false, ...outputItem })
```

if you want to pass two parameters do the following:

```
handleItem = (data: Output, { isValid: boolean }) => {}
```

afterwards you can do:

```
handleItem (outputItem, { isValid: false })
```

Answer (score 2):

`&` is a type *intersection*. `Output & { isValid: boolean }` means it expects something as argument that conforms both to the interface `Output` *and* `{ isValid: boolean }`. In other words, it expects one object which has an `isValid` property and whatever else `Output` defines.

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax expect the property `isValid` of data to be boolean