# Difference between extending and intersecting interfaces in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, intersection, extends

Let's say the following type is defined:

```
interface Shape {
  color: string;
}
```

Now, consider the following ways to add additional properties to this type:

**Extension**

```
interface Square extends Shape {
  sideLength: number;
}
```

**Intersection**

```
type Square = Shape & {
  sideLength: number;
}
```

What is the difference between both approaches?

And, for sake of completeness and out of curiosity, are there other ways to yield comparable results?

Comment: **See Also**: [Interfaces vs. Intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#interfaces-vs-intersections)

Comment: @KyleMit the docs only states "The principle difference between the two is how conflicts are handled". It doesn't explain how conflicts are handled differently which in the end is not helpful enough. The answer below should be in the docs. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Website/blob/6accc6c7f5f14ed91f93d1afcbec9c05f7dc1669/packages/documentation/copy/en/handbook-v2/Object%20Types.md?plain=1#L459 We could open a PR with it :)

Comment: One use for intersecting vs extending types: combining two interfaces: `type NewInterface = FirstInterface & SecondInterface;`

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Yes there are differences which may or may not be relevant in your scenario.

Perhaps the most significant is the difference in how members with the same property key are handled when present in both types.

Consider:

```
interface NumberToStringConverter {
  convert: (value: number) => string;
}

interface BidirectionalStringNumberConverter extends NumberToStringConverter {
  convert: (value: string) => number;
}
```

The `extends` above results in an error because the derriving interface declares a property with the same key as one in the derived interface but with an incompatible signature.

```
error TS2430: Interface 'BidirectionalStringNumberConverter' incorrectly extends interface 'NumberToStringConverter'.

  Types of property 'convert' are incompatible.
      Type '(value: string) => number' is not assignable to type '(value: number) => string'.
          Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
              Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

However, if we employ intersection types

```
type NumberToStringConverter = {
  convert: (value: number) => string;
}

type BidirectionalStringNumberConverter = NumberToStringConverter & {
  convert: (value: string) => number;
}
```

There is no error whatsoever and, furthermore, this is useful indeed as a value conforming to this particular intersection type is easily conceived of.

```
const converter: BidirectionalStringNumberConverter = {
    convert: (value: string | number) => {
        return (
          typeof value === 'string'
            ? Number(value)
            : String(value)
          ) as string & number; // type assertion is an unfortunately necessary hack.
    }
}
```

Note that the implementation of the intersection, as shown above, involves some awkward types and assertions but these are purely implementation artifacts which do not contribute to the type of the converter object which is solely determined by the type `BidirectionalStringNumberConverter` used to annotate the object literal `converter`.

```
const s: string = converter.convert(0); // `convert`'s call signature comes from `NumberToStringConverter`

const n: number = converter.convert('a'); // `convert`'s call signature comes from `BidirectionalStringNumberConverter`
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4BUD2BlYqCWAdgOYDCmhAbmsGlALxQDeAUFO1AMYXWrABcUABSUAhgBs4EQYUQpUASgYA+KAGc8RYgG4WAXxYtQkKACF8AE3yoInYPgoTcBEvGRpyVGnUYAyWHJoWM5anry0qFD+rBxcPDSCIhJSghouxEr0qrLuqLp6uiwA9EVQAIKEFlDAABb4alD1UKJQxJiYVbVajZUQEFWiDS1iktDchABmmKgI3cCY1TXQxtBNEIP44iBxhJwQ+NQWLOMaO+FoguZWNnYOhE6aroGoYd6RjDEc4+GJIynqj2IUAAPlAcvJMqpPrF2DZgHBUIRhCtMBMoH9oPQsVAAORpLQ4qAAfgCuSSoyUghCJHJUgUSkGAPSUTBz20UBK1XA0EGahod0aQyRcEm03h91oWzBtggajUolQ2xqok4AGsAHRsDgGAwnYDqVKAhhnN7q740IQABgU7M5AANzXw7XiuBJxOp8MQJQixpgELKoBNUH6oHa3PJgoDXnw0HbDHqwTJnsbHREzfE+EIcaIcTaOaUHRngM6Gpw3R6vaJ4TY4v6GkGQ3artZbPZHOJqcRwx4i7GgA)

This leads to another interesting difference, `interface` declarations are open ended. New members can be added anywhere because multiple `interface` declarations with same name in the same declaration space are *merged*.

Here is a common use for merging behavior

**lib.d.ts**

```
interface Array<T> {
  // map, filter, etc.
}
```

**array-flat-map-polyfill.ts**

```
interface Array<T> {
  flatMap<R>(f: (x: T) => R[]): R[];
}

if (typeof Array.prototype.flatMap !== 'function') {
  Array.prototype.flatMap = function (f) { 
    // Implementation simplified for exposition. 
    return this.map(f).reduce((xs, ys) => [...xs, ...ys], []);
  }
}
```

Notice how no `extends` clause is present, although specified in separate files the interfaces are both in the global scope and are merged by name into a single logical interface declaration that has both sets of members. (the same can be done for module scoped declarations with slightly different syntax)

By contrast, intersection types, as stored in a `type` declaration, are closed, not subject to merging.

There are many, many differences. You can read more about both constructs in the TypeScript Handbook. The [Object Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#1) and the [Creating Types from Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-types.html) sections are particularly relevant.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for pointing out the difference in behaviour when 'overriding' properties, didn't know about that. That alone is a good reason to use types in certain use cases.

Can you point out situations where interface merging is useful? Are there valid use cases when building applications (in other words: not libraries)?

Comment: Willem Aart as you suggest, it is most useful for writing libraries, but what is an application if not a collection of libraries (including your own app). It can be extremely useful for applications as well. Ex: `interface Object {hasOwnProperty<T, K extends string>(this: T, key: K): this is {[P in K]?}}` which turns `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` into a type guard by 
introducing an additional, more specific signature for it.
.

Comment: @AluanHaddad the `StringToNumberConverter` type should be instead named `BidirectionalStringNumberConverter`, correct? It seems like the other instances were possibly renamed...

Comment: Is this still correct?  I plug your examples into the typescript playground and the compiler complains.

Comment: @NathanChappell thank you for catching that. I don't know when that broke. I've updated the example to make it compile, but it now requires a type assertion. I will look into this more.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks.  TS seems to be changing quite fast, so it's probably impossible to keep up with it (especially since they seem to have abandoned maintaining a specification...)

Comment: Why is `string & number` not evaluated as `never`?

Comment: @cbdeveloper because TypeScript doesn't special case such an intersection even though it is indeed impossible at runtime due to the nature of primitives in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has updated their documentation with a section describing this scenario!

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#interfaces-vs-intersections

"The principle difference between the two is how conflicts are handled, and that difference is typically one of the main reasons why you’d pick one over the other between an interface and a type alias of an intersection type."

Comment: This literally says nothing. I found it in the Handbook and needed to google the answer, because the Handbook is so vague about it.