# Is there any difference between interface and type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've been asked a questino at work and I am unable to answer it.

The question is how it's different to create a:

```
interface A {
  name: string | null;
}
```

than:

```
type A = {name: string | null};
```

I feel like it's compiled down to the same thing, but I need someone wiser than me to expalin in detail.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/52681316/1915893

Comment: Don't have duplicate rights. 
But I think you can find your answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types

Comment: Thank you @ErnestasButa