# Difference between intersection and merged types `{ foo } & { bar }` and `{ foo, bar }` in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

Consider the types `FooBar1` and `FooBar2` defined as follows:

```
type Foo = { foo: string };
type Bar = { bar: number };
type FooBar1 = Foo & Bar;
type FooBar2 = { foo: string; bar: number };
```

#### Question: What is the difference between `FooBar1` and `FooBar2`?

---

**My attempt / research:**

- They are bidirectionally assignable to each other!
  (checked manually and with [`tsd`](https://github.com/SamVerschueren/tsd) - [see here](https://github.com/SamVerschueren/tsd/issues/67#issuecomment-616747097))
- Still, they are not identical to each other! (checked with [`tsd`](https://github.com/SamVerschueren/tsd) - [see here](https://github.com/SamVerschueren/tsd/issues/67#issuecomment-616747097))
- VSCode's intellisense does not collapse `{ foo } & { bar }` automatically into `{ foo, bar }`, while it does collapse other complex types to simpler forms, such as `NonNullable<string | undefined>` to `string`:

```
// |------------------------------------------------------------|
// | let x: {                                                   |
// |     a: string;                                             |
// | } & {                                                      |
// |     b: string;                                             |
// | }                                                          |
// | -----------------------------------------------------------|
//  ^
//  | When hovering `x` here:
//  |
let x: { a: string } & { b: string };
```

---

*Edit:* [Difference between extending and intersecting interfaces in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52681316/4135063) has been suggested as a duplicate but I disagree. Instead of comparing an intersection to the extension of an interface, I am comparing an intersection to another raw type, no interfaces or extensions involved.

Comment: After noticing two votes to close, I have edited the question making it simpler and to the point. Hopefully these votes can be retracted now. Let me know if I should improve anything else.

Comment: Which typescript compiler version do you use? With `3.8.3` it compiles without warning like expected (Your attempt from Github).

Comment: @WolverinDEV Hi, thanks, yes I use 3.8.3 too, it compiles, yes, but compiling is not the issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug in TSD and it just cannot figure out those two are identical.

Comment: `tsd` uses `isTypeIdenticalTo` from `tsc` to check whether two types are identical, but the check gets really complex really fast so I didn't check why those two types aren't identical. The current language versions don't define this relationship, so it might not be a relevant question to ask for a language user, and it's just a compiler detail. The compiler uses some flags to distinguish Object from Intersection types. The distinction may become relevant with something like "complement types" (e.g not (A & B) == not A | not B)

Comment: @artcorpse Hi, any chance you can expand your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3):

In your example, we can say that `FooBar1` and `FooBar2` are equal. And we can indeed prove that:

```
type Equals<A, B> =
    A extends B
    ? B extends A
      ? true
      : false
    : false

type test0 = Equals<{a: 1} & {b: 2}, {a: 1, b: 2}> // true
```

But for a general answer, we can only say that they are not always equal. Why? Because intersections can resolve to `never` in some cases. If ts finds an intersection to be valid, it proceeds with it, otherwise returns `never`.

```
import {O} from "ts-toolbelt"

type O1 = {a: 1, b: 2}
type O2 = {a: 1} & {b: 2}       // intersects properly
type O3 = {a: 1, b: 2} & {b: 3} // resolved to `never`

type test0 = Equals<O1, O2>
// true

type test1 = O.Merge<{a: 1, b: 2}, {b: 3, c: 4}>
// {a: 1, b: 2, c: 4}
```

Here type `O3` resolved to `never` because `b` is `3` and it cannot overlap with `2`. Let's change our example to show that an intersection would work if you had:

```
import {A} from "ts-toolbelt"

type O4 = A.Compute<{a: 1, b: number} & {b: 2}> // {a: 1, b: 2}
type O5 = A.Compute<{a: 1, b: 2} & {b: number}> // {a: 1, b: 2}
```

This example also highlights how intersections work -- like union intersections. TypeScript will go over all the property types and intersect them. We've forced TypeScript to compute the result of the intersection with `A.Compute`.

In short, if ts cannot overlap ALL OF the members, then the product of that intersection is `never`. For this reason, it might not be suitable as a merging tool:

```
type O3 = {a: 1, b: 2} & {b: 3} // resolved to `never`
```

So remember, `&` is not a merging tool. `A & B` is only equal to `{...A, ...B}` only if they have keys that do not overlap. If you need a merging type, use `O.Merge`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am confused. What is direct answer to the question? What is the difference between FooBar1 and FooBar2?

Comment: Also, what is the difference between "intent to merge" and "intent to use &"? Thanks :)

Comment: The right answer is that they are not always equal.

Comment: For most people, when they use `&` is to merge two types, or narrow a union. But the real intent of `&` is to intersect, not merge. This is not very useful on objects since it can easily yield you a `never`. The `&` operator behaves on objects the very same way it behaves on unions. The thing to remember is while `&` can be used for merging to a certain extent, it's not a merging tool. So if you want to merge objects, use ts-toolbelt which uses `&` (internally) responsibly to achieve just that.

Comment: You are saying that "they are not always equal", I think I get that, you're talking about usage of & in general. But I want to understand my specific example. Either FooBar1 and FooBar2 are equal or are different. Which is it?

Comment: Also, can you edit your code to include what does `test1` resolve to (you said it "works" but it's not clear what that means). Thanks :)

Comment: I've updated it. Let me know if I can help with anything else

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the delay to reply. In your first sentence you "proved" that they are equal by showing that they both extend each other. But as mentioned in the question, I already know that they are assignable to each other. This is indeed a necessary condition for them to be equal, but it is not sufficient.

Comment: For example, `string` and `any` both extend each other as well, and they are definitely not equal. So maybe you could improve your proof by saying that *"they both extend each other and are not `any`"*, but how do you know that's enough? How do you know there isn't yet another subtle condition? Since the `tsd` library is saying they are not equal, and it uses TS internals under the hood, it seems to me that there must be a difference.

Comment: This is precisely what I used in the ts-toolbelt https://github.com/millsp/ts-toolbelt/blob/master/src/Any/Equals.ts and that they use in tsd. This is a stricter version of equals is explained in the comments of https://stackoverflow.com/a/52473108/3570903

Comment: While this is very useful to check strict equality (readonly properties, any, etc...), it is mostly to pass tests on types (on the ts-toolbelt). For programmers, at program-time, the more lenient version of Equals should be enough.

Comment: So to answer you question. What is different about the two types? It is that they do not share the same structure, but they are structurally equivalent. TypeScript has a structural type system. stackoverflow.com/a/52473108/3570903 effectively uses a clever technique to discern between equivalence and pure equality.