# Extend react.component and '&' sign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

**What is the "&" sign in a class definition?**

In my class I found out that I need the following class definition:

`class myList extends Component<RouteComponentProps<any> & IMyList> {`

I find many other examples with *comma* instead of *&*, but with comma I get the error:

> prop x does not exist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875609/typescript-operator

Comment: instead of using an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) you should probably let `IMyList` extend `RouteComponentProps<any>`

Comment: @Thomas Not necessarily, either way will work for component props. `&` means intersection ie the props will be `RouteComponentProps<any>` and `IMyList`. Putting a `,` mean you are passing the other type parameter (for state) and thus props will be `RouteComponentProps<any>` and state will be `IMyList`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I know that both ways will work. It just seems to me that the OP is very inexperienced. And although I'm confident that he will soon understand these types, I think that it is way easier for an inexperienced programmer to create a big mess and repeat yourself all over the place with this construct. That's why I recommend to use inheritance instead.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, from that point of view I agree, inheritance may be easier to grasp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&` operator is called [Intersection Type](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html#intersection-type)

It allows you to

> ...take two objects and create a new one that has the features of both these objects.

Think about it as "a type which is both typeA and typeB". I.E. a new type with properties from each object in the intersection type declaration.

P.S. I strongly suggest you to read the book in the link. It was very helpful for me.