# What do "&" and"|" after a type name mean in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I saw a typescript code like

```
type Point = PartialPointX & { y: number; };
```

and I know '&' in javascript is "and",'|' is "OR", do they work different in typescript?

Answer (score 3):

That is an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types). Basically it combines multiple types into one so your new type `Point` is an object with the properties of `PartialPointX` and `{ y: number; }`.

Comment: I know this,I don't understand why is "&" work different from js.

Comment: @caochamp Because this is Typescript.

Comment: When used on types (like in your question), they are the intersection ('&') and union ('|') operators. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875609/typescript-operator answer for more details.

When used on numbers, in Typescript and Javascript, they are bitwise operators (for AND and OR operations). See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp.