# Why does typescript give a type error on type unions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, union-types

Whenever I have to work with objects that have a combined union type, typescript complains about the properties that I try to access and I don't get autocompletion either. For example this:

```
interface A {
  id: string;
  value: number;
}

interface B {
  result: string;
}

export type Types = A | B;

function test(obj: Types) {
  obj.result;  // want to work with obj as though it implements interface B
}
```

I get errors when I access `result`, `id`, and `value` from typescript:

```
Property 'result' does not exist on type 'Types'.
  Property 'result' does not exist on type 'A'
```

Is there any way that I can narrow down the interface type so that I would get a better IDE experience?

Comment: You need a [*type guard*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) in one way or another.

Comment: Because `result` only exists on `B`, if your `obj` is a `A` , then accessing `result` on it will return `undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
interface A {
  type:'A';
  id: string;
  value: number;
}

interface B {
  type:'B';
  result: string;
}

export type Types = A | B;

function test(obj: Types) {
  if(obj.type==='B'){
    obj.result;
  }
}
```

You need a common field to teach TS how to recognize type A or B.

> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions

Answer (score 3):

If you want that action you can use `&` operator
like

```js
type Types = A & B
```

you can merge A interface and B interface. It's naming **Intersection Types**

And I can write some info about this. Can you wait some minutes?

### Reference

1. [About & Intersection Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875609/typescript-operator)
2. [About Union Tpyes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)

---

And now I know that what I got it was wrong. So if you want to use type gaurd it's work for you.

```js
enum ALPHA_TYPE {
   A = "A",
   B = "B"
}
interface A {
   ...
}
interface B {
   ...
}
export type Types<T extends ALPHA_TYPE> = T extends A ? A : B

function test<T>(obj: Types<T>) {
  obj.result;  // want to work with obj as though it implements interface B
}
```

and you can use like

```
text<ALPHA_TYPE.A>()
```

Comment: Sure, would love an explanation. Have been searching for an answer for very long

Answer (score 0):

```
interface A {
  id: string;
  value: number;
}

interface B {
  result: string;
}

 type Types = A | B;

function test(obj: Types) {
  const objB = obj as B; // Introduce a new variable and cast it as B
  objB.result; // Happy!!!
}
```

Just introduce a new variable and cast it to B, then you get to call `.result` on the object.
[image]