# How to access variable exported from a page in _app.tsx?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Let's say this is my `pages/visitor.tsx`

```
const PageQuery = 'my query';

const Visitor = () => {
  return <div>Hello, World!</div>;
};

export default Visitor;
```

How do I access `PageQuery` in `_app.tsx`?

It appears that *one way* to do it is by attaching `PageQuery` as a property to the component function, e.g.,

```
const PageQuery = 'my query';

const Visitor = () => {
  return <div>Hello, World!</div>;
};

Visitor.PageQuery = PageQuery;

export default Visitor;
```

Now inside of `_app.tsx` I can access it like so:

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  Component.PageQuery;
}
```

However, I was wondering if I am just overlooking a canonical way to access exports for every page when it is being loaded.

Comment: `import Visitor, { PageQuery } from "./visitor.tsx";`...?

Comment: Each page has its own `PageQuery`. I need whichever is currently being loaded by next.js

Comment: Right. That wasn't in the original question. Update your question to include *all* relevant details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are first class objects in javascript. Any react functional component is just another function and it can have custom properties.

```
const Visitor = () => {
  return <div>Hello, World!</div>;
};
Visitor.PageQuery = 'my query';

export default Visitor;
```

Now you can make use of this in `_app.tsx`

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
 const query = Component.PageQuery ?? '';
...

}
```

**Note:** You might face issue with Typescipt. TS is not aware of the property you have just added.

So you might need to extend the default types using [`&`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875609/typescript-operator) :

```
type NextPageWithQuery<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
  PageQuery?: string;
};
```

```
type AppPropsWithPageQuery = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout;
};
```

and accordingly this will change:

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithPageQuery) => {
 const query = Component.PageQuery ?? '';
...

}
```